# Cannot set up tensorflow gpu object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I tried to follow a tutorial on how to setup tensorflow gpu (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc) but on the jupyter step i am getting this error :https://pastebin.com/gm3g8cC5
(ive set in in a pastebin because its very long)
I dont know what to do, ive also tried others tutorial but none of the others works, they also got errors ( but they are differents) at the jupyter step.

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.12.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.12.*.')
```

Here is the part where the errors pops.
I dont know what is my tensorflow version since when i am trying to import it i am getting `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: *＋1* for removing the Samba configuration question.